# Visual Studio using wrong account to connect to SQL Server

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2000, connection-string

I'm having trouble trying to get Visual Studio to connect to a database located on another server.

Here is my connection string :

```
<add name="CDDMSDB" connectionString="Database=CDDMS;Server=aecl-db01.domainx.local;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=7200"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now when I try to connect via my app, I get the following error : 
Login failed for user 'DOMAINX\CDSDEV_NATHANIE$'.

The Account DOMAINX\CDSDEV_NATHANIE, does not exist. I am logged in under the account empower\nathanielp, but it does not seem to be using that account at all. I can connect to the SQL Server through Management Studio just fine using empower\nathanielp, but for whatever reason its not using that account when I run the app.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28VS.71%29.aspx

According to this it is pulling your windows account credentials when you are trying to log into the database and that could explain the "The Account DOMAINX\CDSDEV_NATHANIE, does not exist." IF your windows account credentials doesn't exist on the server you are connecting too.

I would set `Integrated Security=false` and put the username and password you are logging into the server under in your connection string. using `User ID=` and `Password=` Hope this helps.